# Is there an analogue to WorkItem.Save(SaveFlags.MergeAll) in WorkItem REST API?

Tags: tfs, concurrency, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, tfs-workitem

We have recently fully migrated our old fat (`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client`) client code to use [WorkItem REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) instead.

The issue is that our old code saved WorkItems using the [WorkItem.Save(SaveFlags.MergeAll)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/ff732579%28v%3Dvs.110%29) calls

```
WorkItem.Save(SaveFlags.MergeAll)
```

that was resilient against compatible concurrent changes.

While new code is plain

```
WiClient.UpdateWorkItemAsync(updates, Id, expand: WorkItemExpand.All)
```

that will unfortunately sometimes result in

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssServiceException: TF26071: This work item has been changed by someone else since you opened it.  You will need to refresh it and discard your changes.
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.d__53.MoveNext()

because of some irrelevant concurrent changes.

So, is there an analogue to `WorkItem.Save(SaveFlags.MergeAll)` with REST API, or do we have to handle such failures manually where appropiate?

P.S.: Well, I understand that there are probably [no](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47198070/3745022) analogues, but...

Comment: `bypassRules = true` doesn't help?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk As far as I understand it only deals with WI validation rules (like field can only have a value of A, B, C) and not with any concurrency violations.

Comment: You are right, but I thought maybe it worth to try....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, REST API doesn't have this function. You would just try to rerun your api.

If you do want this function, you may submit a user voice at the website below:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21